# From InkScape to InDesign: How to import AND EDIT a vector graphic artwork illustration?

Tags: copy-paste, inkscape, vector-graphics, adobe-indesign, workflow

I would like to import/copy a vector graphic made in InkScape **and be able to EDIT the vector paths** in InDesign CC. Simple copy-paste doesn't work: pastes nothing in inDesign.

At the moment I export the artworks from InkScape as EPS files, then import those files in InDesign, however, the editability is lost and the files are sharp but uneditable. Any ideas how to do this *without using/buying any other (expensive) software such as adobe illustrator etc?*

Comment: have you tried SVG format? or try PDF

Comment: thanks @masgo well I already tried the open format svg, but indesign doesnt understand/support that formaat hels. so that didnt work. pdf is a great idea I shall try that and report back!